Determine whether the following infinite sum converges or not.

Let $\lambda, \mu \in \left (0, \frac {1} {2} \right ).$ Then determine whether the following sum converges or not $:$ $$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left \lvert \sum\limits_{m = 0}^{n} \frac {\Gamma (\lambda + m)} {m!} \frac {\Gamma (\lambda + n - m)} {(n - m)!} \right \rvert^2 \frac {\Gamma (n + 1)} {\Gamma (n + 2 - 2 \mu)}.$$

I found this series while working with an estimation of an integral involving Bergman kernel of the symmetrized bidisc (which I prefer not to disclose due to privacy constraint). I am trying to investigate whether the sum is finite failing to which the integral estimate I am looking for would not hold. But I have no idea how to make sure whether the sum is finite or not. I have tried to use Stirling's approximation but unfortunately that would lead me to nowhere.
Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your valuable time.

Mathematica gives $\frac{\pi ^2 \csc ^2(\pi  \lambda ) \Gamma (\lambda )^2 \Gamma (-4 \lambda -2 \mu +2)}{\Gamma (1-\lambda )^2 \Gamma (-2 (\lambda +\mu -1))^2}$.

@JimB$:$ That means we need to have $2 \lambda + \mu < 1$  in order for the sum to converge. Right?

There's a bit more to it.  First, where the formula I gave results in a value, the sum converges.  But when there's a combination of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ where the formula doesn't work, that doesn't necessarily mean that the sum doesn't converge for those values.  I'll write more later.  Just don't have time right now.

@JimB$:$ Okay. I was just wondering how do we define $\Gamma (-4 \lambda - 2 \mu + 2)$ if $2 \lambda + \mu \geq 1.$

I take back my comment about "where the formula I gave results in a value, the sum converges."  I see now that's not true.

In my old age I have others (such as Mathematica) do my algebra for me so the steps are not given to be completely convincing in the following answer.
The inner sum can be symbolically determined with the following:
s1 = Sum[Gamma[\[Lambda] + m] Gamma[\[Lambda] + n - m]/(m! (n - m)!), {m, 0, n},
  Assumptions -> {0 < \[Lambda] < 1, n \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers}, 
  GenerateConditions -> True]^2 // FullSimplify

$$s_1=\frac{\pi  16^{-\lambda } \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-\lambda \right)^2 \Gamma (\lambda )^2 \csc ^2(\pi  (\lambda +n))}{\Gamma (n+1)^2 \Gamma (-n-2 \lambda +1)^2}$$
The outer sum is now found with
s2 = Sum[s1  Gamma[n + 1]/Gamma[n + 2 - 2 \[Mu]], {n, 0, \[Infinity]},
  Assumptions -> {0 < \[Lambda] < 1/2, 0 < \[Mu] < 1/2},
  GenerateConditions -> True]

$$\fbox{$\frac{\pi  16^{-\lambda } \csc ^2(\pi  \lambda ) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} (1-2 \lambda )\right)^2 \Gamma (\lambda )^2 \Gamma (-2 (2 \lambda +\mu -1))}{\Gamma (1-2 \lambda )^2 \Gamma (-2 (\lambda +\mu -1))^2}\text{ if }2 \lambda +\mu <1$}$$
So (contrary to some of my initial comments) no claims are made when $2\lambda+\mu \geq 1$.  So what about $\lambda=3/8$ and $\mu=3/8$ where $2\lambda+\mu \geq 1$?
\[Lambda] = 3/8;
\[Mu] = 3/8;
s1 = Sum[Gamma[\[Lambda] + m] Gamma[\[Lambda] + n - m]/(m! (n - m)!), {m, 0, n},
   Assumptions -> n \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers]^2

$$s_1=\frac{\sqrt{2} \pi  \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^2 \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)^2}{\Gamma \left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^2 \Gamma (n+1)^2}$$
s2 = Sum[s1  Gamma[n + 1]/Gamma[n + 2 - 2 \[Mu]], {n, 0, \[Infinity]},
  GenerateConditions -> True]



Could you kindly check the supremum of the sum $$\sup\limits_{w = \left (w_1, w_2 \right ) \in \mathbb D^2} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left \lvert \sum\limits_{m = 0}^{n} \frac {\Gamma \left (\frac {\lambda} {2} + m \right )} {m!} \frac {\Gamma (\lambda + n - m)} {(n - m)!} \overline {w_1}^m \overline {w_2}^{n - m} \right \rvert^2 \frac {\Gamma (n + 1)} {\Gamma (n + 2 - 2 \mu)}.$$ Here $\mathbb D^2$ denotes the bidisc $\mathbb D \times \mathbb D$ and $\lambda > 0$ and $0 < \mu < \frac {1} {2}.$

You can download the Wolfram Engine for free (but not for commercial use) at https://www.wolfram.com/engine/ to carry out such sums.
